# CSS sheet won't load onto website for Geocities.

Tags: html, css

Recently, I loaded my index.html and my stylesheet.css to my Geocities directory, and I can't get the css file to load onto the website.  The site only shows the HTML code.  After using Googlefu, I thought I figured it out, but still failed.  Below is what I have in my  & CSS.  The index.html file is in the root folder, and my css file is in a /css root.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
```

The css document just contains code to change the navigation bar at the top of the page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `href=""` starts with a slash: `/css/stylesheet.css` which means it's expecting it at the website root, but Geocities puts websites in subdirectories, so removing the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

Since your index is in the root folder, try to use this code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">`

Comment: I have tried this solution, and it still will not load the CSS code to the site.  I double checked the code in my CSS   sheet to make sure there were not any errors, that is good, so it should load.

Comment: What is the name of your css file? Make sure it is CSS file.

Comment: Name of the CSS file is "stylesheet".  It shows on the file manager that it is a CSS document.

Comment: Alright then. Can you provide your folder/file structure? Just update you question above with the structure.

Comment: Actually, I managed to fix it.  Apparently, I needed to make the code this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />